# BitmapSource SourceStream contains only zeros

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I'm trying to use DevExpress ImageEdit control to get access to Image Stream.

I have property `ImageSource` which is binded to `Source` property of ImageEdit control:

```
public BitmapImage ImageSource { get; set; }
```

Then I'm trying to do following:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[255];
ImageSource.StreamSource.Read(bytes, 0, 255);
```

And the problem is, that this stream contains only zeros. (In example I read 255 bytes, but whole stream is ZERO.

Could you tell me what am I doing wrong? How can I get stream from that?

Comment: You are not checking result (read count) of `Read` call to start with...

Comment: `CanRead = true` and `Length = 2239542`. Is that what you mean? I mentioned that I'm reading only 255  bytes to show the problem

Comment: `Stream.Read(byte[], int, int)` returns an `int` containing the amount of bytes read.

Comment: strange... is it possible that it started working when I have added `var readbytes = ` to the call?

Comment: no. It only depends on Position - likely whatever read stream before your code did not do it on re-run.

Comment: So, it's kind of inpredictable... sometimes it's working, sometimes not... I have no idea why

Comment: Ok I have found a problem... It is working with *.bmp images, not with others... But right now: how to do it for jpgs and pngs? (ImageEdit control returns BitmapImage from it's Source property)